# Adding 'Declared Value' for UPS Shipping... possible? [Magento]

Tags: magento, ups

I am tasked with the needing to be able to add a declared value for certain products on my magento store for UPS shipping. Doing some research, it doesn't appear they have it set up for the grab that magento executes to get their shipping estimates from UPS.com because I just can't find where the linking could be. Looking into FedEx's files, they DO have a process that gets ran;

```
$declaredValue = $xml->addChild('DeclaredValue');
$declaredValue->addChild('Value', $r->getValue());
$declaredValue->addChild('CurrencyCode', $this->getCurrencyCode());
```

I absolutely don't think just plug and play would work here, whereas UPS may not even recognize that search for the declared value. So I suppose my question would be, has anyone ever dealt with this kind of issue, and if it is possible to add such a grab to the UPS search, what would the created attribute on the product inside magento be found at? Simply 'DeclaredValue'?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [magento.se]

Comment: I added the magento tag, didn't know if that was enough, but I will look into the stackexchange too! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is code that sets the declared value in the FedEx rate request. Your UPS rate coding should have something similar, if it doesn't then look for an alternate module or else you will need to adjust or write your own.